# Symfony2 supported NoSQL databases?

Tags: symfony, nosql

What are the NoSQL databases which can be used with Symfony2 ?
What is the preferred one for Symfony2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB can easily be used with the [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html), it really look like to the Doctrine ORM.